# How do I access a file in a project folder - Windows 8 store app?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, file-access

I've got a Windows 8 store app where I've created an "App_Data" folder. I added an sqlite database file and now I'm trying to get the file path to create a connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added my existing sqlite file to the project's Common folder and I set the Build Action to Content. You cannot write to this file, so you need to copy it to the application's local storage folder. I created a StorageManagement class to initialized my database when the application starts up.

```
    public static class StorageManagement
    {
        public static async Task<bool> DoesFileExistAsync(string file)
        {
            try
            {
                await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(file);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static async void InitializeDatabaseAsync()
        {
            if (!DoesFileExistAsync("MyDb.sqlite").Result)
            {
                string databaseFile = Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, @"Common\MyDb.sqlite");
                StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(databaseFile);
                await file.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
            }
        }
    }
```

If the database file isn't already in the local storage folder, only then will it copy the file from the common folder. I can then create my sqlite connection using the file in the local storage.

Comment: Just a heads up with this code, the DoesFileExistAsync("MyDb.sqlite").Result will result in blocking the current thread and isn't asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to construct a uri to the file and then use that to access the file.

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/app_data/database.data");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

The other approach is to use the ApplicationData class.

```
var folder = await ApplictionData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("app_data");
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("database.data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created this "app_data" folder in your project folder? This won't work because you can only directly access files saved in the apps isolated storage, or you need the user to select the file from using the filepicker, before you can access it in the app

Comment: Yeah, I thought that this would be the case. I was able to set the build action property on the file to Content, which enables me to read-only. Doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.  I needed to read JSON from a text file that will be packaged as part of the app as an intermediate step before we have a service that produces the JSON.

Using LocalStorage wasn't the answer here, InstalledLocation is the thing to use to read a file packaged as part of the app, like so:

```
    var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("app_data\\tempjsonfile.json");
    String json = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

This reads from a json file in an app_data directory I created in the project.  Essential: in the properties for the JSON file, set the Build Action to 'Content' and Copy to Output Directory to 'Copy Always'.