# Access MHT File from Solution Directory in Windows 8.1 App

Tags: vb.net, webview, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, file-access

I have an MHT (Microsoft web archive) file that I have added to my project folder. I need this file to display in a WebView on a help page. I have set the file's build action to "Content," like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645440/how-do-i-access-a-file-in-a-project-folder-windows-8-store-app) reccomended. I then use this code in the page's `Loaded` event handler.

```
    Try
        Dim strHelpNavigate = Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.ToString(), "\MyAppsHelp.mht")
        webHelp.Navigate(New Uri(strHelpNavigate))
    Catch ex As Exception
        webHelp.NavigateToString("<html><head><style>body {font-family: segoe ui; color: white; background-color: black;}</style></head><body><h2>Sorry, the help page is currently unavailable.</h2></body></html>")
    End Try
```

This code produces an exception: `{"Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."}`

I have also tried passing `"\MyAppsHelp.mht"` to the `Navigate` method like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443835/locating-and-reading-a-file-stored-locally) reccomended, but this produces the same exception, and I see from the Local window that the string passed to the `Navigate` method is the same either way.

Does anyone have any advice on how to display this file in the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

WebView does not natively support HTML archive files, but you can do the work convert these files to html + images if you're so inclined.

Open the .mht file in notepad, and you'll see that there are separate sections for each part of the HTML file - you can parse these sections to get the HTML out, then the base64 encoded images, then save them in your local app folder and use WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri to load them. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/20/a-primer-on-webview-navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx for details on how to use this method.

OF course, if it's a static file that you will be using all of the time, it would be far easier to just convert it before packaging the app.

Comment: thanks for the input about the MHT files. However, after implementing your solution and stepping through the code, I discovered that this looks for the files in the app's `LocalFolder`, and my file resides in the project folder/solution explorer. Do you know how to access the file from there?

Comment: I think this is what you want: ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

Comment: No, that accesses the same folder as "ms-appdata:///Local," which is the folder the URI resolver accesses.